# SSL Certificate on Joomla site?

Tags: ssl

How can I implement SSL Certificate on my site on Joomla?

I already try to enable it from the administration global configuration but it did not work as it's supposed to. So, are there's w way to install SSL Certificate directly or on Terminal?

Comment: You should take this up with your hosting provider

Answer (score 1):

Many of the best hosting companies now provide SSL certificates for free and these are sometimes enabled by default.

Browse to the https version of your website and you'll soon see if this is the case with your own hosting provider (look for the padlock etc).

There may be an option in cPanel for you to enable this yourself. Look for "Let's Encrypt" or similar.

If you can't find an option to enable SSL, then talk to your hosting provider as they may have a paid SSL option.

Once the SSL Certificate is enabled, you can then enable the appropriate option in `System -> Global Configuration -> Server -> Force HTTPS` e.g. set this to: "Entire Site".

The Force HTTPS option in Joomla doesn't always seem to work reliably for me so I usually include this in my .htaccss file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```